# Edge Browser PDF starting not on page 1

Tags: pdf, microsoft-edge

All,

We have multiple PDFs for press releases on our corporate website. For some reason, when clicking on them while using Edge, the PDFs tend to start on the last page. This does not happen in non-Edge browsers. The #page=<#> URL declaration has no effect in Edge, so I'm not sure [a] why they are opening to a page other than #1 or [b] how to force it to open them to the correct page.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried opening it with e.g. adobe reader? The pdf might contain some "initial view" metadata that makes it open on page #n

Comment: Thanks for the thought, but, yeah, the initial view is correctly set to page 1. It works fine in Chrome and in IE, but Edge's built-in viewer seems to do what ever it feels like.